# Remapping URLS in web.config

Tags: url, web-config, seo, url-rewriting

I need to add a term to the URL's within a sub-directory of a website I'm working on to boost/enhance SEO. For example, http://www.domain.com/shop/product/ should go to http://www.domain.com/shop/product-SEO/ instead. I need to set this up in web.config and looked at examples on here but couldn't find anything similar. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for is called URL Rewriting.
You should have a look at the following link, it will provide everything you need:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx